# How would I make a self-linking <div>?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

After much Googling, I resort to the chance at ridicule and moderation on Stack Exchange.

What I am trying to do sounds simple enough. I want to make a `<div>` id/class that will link automatically create a link to itself via some kind of scripting.

Let me put down some pseudocode, before I make it sound more complicated than it is:

```
#Let div.link = xxx.html
#Let div.pic = xxx.png/jpg

for div in HTMLdocument:
    if div.class == "autolink":
        div = "<a href=\"mysite/" + div.link + "><img src=\"mysite/" + div.pic + "></a>"
```

Now, obviously that's Python pseudocode, but I am familiar(ish) with PHP and Javascript. Basically, I want to make the `div` generate an HTML link without having to actually type out the tags and links for every given `div` on a web page. I want to be able to type, in my `index.html`:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div class = "1"></div>
        <div class = "2"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and then to be presented with a page that has the two `div`s linked, imaged, and, preferably, formatted.

---

Like I said, the problem seems simple, but I can't seem to get it to work right, in any language. This seems like a thing that would be very useful for begiiner web designers.

PERSONAL NOTE:

I would preferably like to see a solution in PHP or Javascript, but if you are good with Django and want to show me how to get it done in that, I would be just as grateful!

=========================================

EXAMPLE:

Let's say you have a browser based RPG, and you want to show your player's inventory. The Inventory page would display the items in a players inventory, complete with a link and image, based on whatever was in that user's inventory page. It would look like this (this is VERY rough output, Statements tagged in #these# are not code, and should be interpereted as what they describe):

```
<h1>User's Inventory:</h1>
<p><div class = "item_1">#Link to page of 'item_1', image of 'item_1'#</div></p>
<p><div class = "item_2">#Link to page of 'item_2', image of 'item_2'#</div></p>
```

The above would display, roughly, a header that said "User's Inventory", and then display a linked image of `item_1`, followed by a newline and then a linked image of `item_2`, where said items would be in a separate file OR a list that lists all the items and their respective links and images.

Comment: The question mentions "I would preferably like to see a solution in PHP." This makes the PHP tag valid (IMO) regardless of whether the problem can be solved in PHP or not.

Comment: Who on earth downvoted this, and why? This is _so_ much better than the plethora of "please finish my homework for me" questions that are taking over Stack Overflow.

Comment: If I got that right, you want a div in which you can dynamically add links and images?

Comment: @BrandonBuck That's true enough, I suppose. :)

Comment: please show us the desired output for the last block code you posted

Comment: @I Can Has Cheezburger Yeha, that's basically it. Essentially, I want the server to look at a list of object pages (that is, a list of pages and their instanced variables `link` and `img`, which could probably be a SQL database, but that's something I haven't learned yet) and add <a hreref> tags based on the div.link/img strings (which would be a link to the html and/or image file on the server)

Comment: "After much Googling, I resort to the chance at ridicule and moderation on Stack Exchange." Joke's on you - by using us as a last resort, you're actually doing it right ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery, and when page dom is loaded, you cycle through each `div` that has the class `autolink` and do your manipulations (add your desired html into each div). You can use the `id` of each `div` to place data inside. You can use a prefix to that id values for different types of data. For example, im using "inventory_" as a prefix.

```
<h1>User's Inventory:</h1>
<p><div class = "autolink" id="inventory_item_1">#Link to page of 'item_1', image of 'item_1'#</div></p>
<p><div class = "autolink" id="inventory_item_1">#Link to page of 'item_2', image of 'item_2'#</div></p>
```

then jquery **on document ready:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () 
    {
        // define your website here
        var mysite = "http://www.example.com/";


        // this will cycle through each div with class autolink. using `this` to reffer to each.
        $(".autolink").each(function () {

            // we get for div with id="inventory_item_1" ...
            var mylink = $(this).attr('id').replace("inventory_",""); // ... a value item_1
            var myimagesrc = $(this).attr('id').replace("inventory_","image_"); // ... image_item_1

            $(this).html('<a href="'+mysite+'showInventory.php?item='+mylink+'"><img src="'+mysite+'images/'+myimagesrc+'.jpg"></a>'); 
            // the above will add html code of this format:
            // <a href="http://www.example.com/showInventory.php?item=item_1"><img src="http://www.example.com/images/image_item_1.jpg"></a>

        });
    });
</script>
```

try it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/5APhT/2/

Answer (score 1):

I'll give a sample in php. Here is an example if you already have a set of links to use

```
<?php
   //Create a multidimensional array to store all you need to create links
   $links['1'][]="http://www.yahoo.com";
   $links['1'][]="yahoo.com";
   $links['2'][]="http://www.facebook.com";
   $links['2'][]="yahoo.com";
   $links['3'][]="http://www.google.com";
   $links['3'][]="yahoo.com";

   foreach($links as $class => $innerArray){
     $link=innerArray[0];
     $linktext=innerArray[1];

     echo "<div class='$class'><a href='$link'>$linktext</a></div>";
   }
```

?>

This creates the divs for you so you don't have to add them in advance.
You can add images in the same manner

Comment: I think I get what you're going for, and it would solve my problem in the short term. If no one else gives me a better answer, I'll accept this in a bit. That said, I would have preferred a more...er, "modular" way of doing it. But, again, this way works.